# How to delete the first 4 rows from multiple excel files using python pandas (Dataframes)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Currently I am writing a program that combines multiple excel spreadsheets.

I would like to know how to delete the first 4 rows from every spreadsheet before combining them. Below is the specific statement attempting to delete the first 4 rows but I am getting an error.

```
frames[0:] = [df.drop(df.index[[0,3]]) for df in frames[0:]]
```

Below is the complete program

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

files = filedialog.askopenfilenames()
print("--------------")
print(files)
ExcelFileNames = [Path(x).name for x in files]
print("--------------")
print(type(ExcelFileNames))
print("--------------")
print(ExcelFileNames)
print("--------------")
print (ExcelFileNames[0])
print("--------------")
print("Number of files is:", len(ExcelFileNames))

# read them in
excels = [pd.ExcelFile(name) for name in ExcelFileNames]

# turn them into dataframes
frames = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[0], header=None,index_col=None) for x in excels]


frames[0:] = [df.drop(df.index[[0,3]]) for df in frames[0:]]
# delete the first row for all frames except the first
# i.e. remove the header row -- assumes it's the first
frames[1:] = [df[1:] for df in frames[1:]]

# concatenate them..
combined = pd.concat(frames)

# write it out
combined.to_excel("DNcombined.xlsx", header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: why not `df[3:]`?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

you can add [skiprows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) to your argument to skip these rows whilst looping over your list.

```
# read them in
excels = [pd.ExcelFile(name) for name in ExcelFileNames]

# turn them into dataframes
frames = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[0], header=None,index_col=None, skiprows=4) for x in excels]
```

Comment: This worked, I changed the skiprows = 14 to skiprows 4, to skip the first 4. I will keep trying to get the dropframes to work though when working with multiple dataframes, but I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @JhangirAwan you can use `.iloc` and filter them out, but its hard to say without seeing what your sample data looks like. sorry I thought i read 14!