# Importing complex Excel with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, import

I have a problem importing data from a complex excel file. The file looks like the following:

[image: Excel spreadsheet]

I want import the data and therefore need to perform two steps:

1. Delete the first 2 rows before importing (this data is not needed)
2. Pivot "Headphones", "TV" and "Radio"

How can I do this?

EDIT:

I want "Headphones", "TV" and "Radio" in a column after "Name" called "product".

So the columns should be: "Country" "Name" "product" "Sales" "Price" " Bestseller"

example:

```
US | Tom | Headphones | 1200 | 100 | Headphone 1 
US | Tom | TV         | 1546 | 500 | TV 1
```

Comment: An example of how to delete the first x rows is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59725186/how-to-delete-the-first-4-rows-from-multiple-excel-files-using-python-pandas-da  (the examples show how to do it with 4 rows).     After this it's pretty unclear what you want to do in step 2, How does your 'expected output' looks like ?

Comment: Thank you for that! It helped me get rid of the first rows. Now I have the problem, that I want "Headphones", "TV" and "Radio" in a column after "Name" called "product". So the columns should be: "Country" "Name" "product" "Sales" "Price" " Bestseller"

One example, since it seems impossible to put a table in this forum, looks like this:
US | Tom | Headphones | 1200 | 100 | Headphone 1
and the next row:
US | Tom | TV | 1546 | 500 | TV 1
I hope that is understandable.

Comment: I added your response to your question....

Comment: I found a way to implement a table and added it below. I hope that makes it clearer what I need. Thank you for your help

Comment: Perfect! Thank you Luuk. I am new to the forum and had no idea how to do it. That looks great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jerry, i am pretty new to python but take a look at this:

```
import pandas as pd

e=pd.ExcelFile("sales.xlsx")
df = e.parse(skiprows=2)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
  if (index==0):
      print("Country|Name|product|Sales|Price|Bestseller")
  else:
      print(row[0], row[1], "Headphones", row[2], row[3],row[4], sep='|')
      print(row[0], row[1], "TV", row[5], row[6], row[7], sep='|')
      print(row[0], row[1], "Radio", row[8], row[9], row[10],sep='|')
```

output:

```
Country|Name|product|Sales|Price|Bestseller
US|Tom|Headphones|1200|100|Headphone 1
US|Tom|TV|1200|100|Headphone 1
US|Tom|Radio|1200|100|Headphone 1
CA|Megan|Headphones|2300|110|Headphone 2
CA|Megan|TV|2300|110|Headphone 2
CA|Megan|Radio|2300|110|Headphone 2
UK|Ryan|Headphones|1156|120|Headphone 1
UK|Ryan|TV|1156|120|Headphone 1
UK|Ryan|Radio|1156|120|Headphone 1
```

This code give a lof of points for improvement, because (i.e) i did 'hard-code' the column names.

EDIT  (because of dataframe is needed as output:

```
mycolumns = ['Country','Name','product','Sales','Price','Bestseller']
i = 0

d = pd.DataFrame(columns=mycolumns)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   if (index>0):
      d.loc[i] = [row[0], row[1],"Headphones",row[2],row[3],row[4]] 
      i = i + 1
      d.loc[i] = [row[0], row[1],"TV",row[5],row[6],row[7]] 
      i = i + 1
      d.loc[i] = [row[0], row[1],"Radio",row[8],row[9],row[10]] 
      i = i + 1
```

More info on [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/frame.html)

Comment: Hey Luuk, thank you very much for your help! I really appreciate the effort you put into it. Sadly I think I badly described what I need. The data needs to be in a dataframe at the end, so I cannot build it that way. I guess it has something to do with Multiindexing and pivoting that, but since I am new to python I am not sure how to get this done...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, that helped getting rid of the first lines. What I have now is:

```html
Unnamed: 0    Unnamed: 1 Headphones  Unnamed: 3  Unnamed: 4    TV      ...
  0  Country  Name        Sales      Price       Bestseller    Sales   ...
  1  US          Tom        1200        100  Headphone 1   1546    ...
  
  # And what I want is
  
  Country Name product     Sales Price Bestseller
  US    Tom  Headphones  1200  100   Headphone 1
  US      Tom  TV          1546  500   TV 1
```